# Return only one record of distinct item with multiple unique locations

Tags: distinct

I am not sure if this could even be done.. but I really only want an item showing up with 1 location to pull stock from rather than two in the mix causing a double pull of inventory... preferably the location with MIN qty, BUT some items have multiple locations of the same qty. This is too deep for me and I've been hounding for ways to return only one location of the 3 even if I cant get the MIN.

Here is my table

```
ITEM        LOC                QTY
R12345      40A1000005          22
R12345      50B0300003          98
R12345      60C2300004          22
```

I wish to return only ONE of the minimal qty locations.

```
ITEM    LOC             QTY
R12345  40A1000005      22


SELECT DISTINCT item,loc,min(qty) as minqty
      FROM whse
           GROUP BY item,loc
         ORDER BY item;
```

This obviously doesn't work and I've tried creating other views and joining them together but I haven't the slightest luck on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't mentioned any Database name, I am assuming you are using Oracle DB.

Here is one of the many solutions :-

```
  with tab (item,loc,qty)
as
(
select 'R12345','40A1000005','22' from dual
union all
select 'R12345','50B0300003','98' from dual
union all
select 'R12345','60C2300004','22' from dual
)
select * from (
select item,loc,qty,dense_rank() over (partition by item order by qty,loc) rn from tab)
where rn=1;
```

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Ohh I understand now! the first matchup ranks above the rest so others are ignored... this is working I believe! Ill implement in my large scale database and see how this works.. thanks!

Comment: I can even remove the 'rn' column from the results by beginning the statement with -- select item,loc,qty from (select . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming mysql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item,loc,min(qty) as minqty
  FROM whse
       GROUP BY item,loc
     ORDER BY item LIMIT 1;
```

So just add a "LIMIT 1"

For other database engines, similar solutions exist.